# How to improve perl Gtk2 performance when we have a large number of widgets

Tags: perl, gtk2

I'm writing a perl GUI using Gtk2, it has a scrolled window which contains a number of GTk2::Expander which includes different widgets.
The poroblem is when i have a large number of Expanders (~80,000) the time it takes to perform show_all() is large, and when i open a single expander it takes several seconds. Running the same script with less expanders give a very fast response.

Since my expanders exists in a scrolled window and only part of them would be really visible, is there a way to improve the performance? like showing only the visible expanders and keeping all others as hidden?

I can't use GTK3, I need to use Perl and Gtk2 only.

Example Code:

```
my $ItemsCount = 10000;
my $ScWin      = Gtk2::ScrolledWindow->new(undef, undef);
my $Frame      = Gtk2::Frame->new('Items');
my $ItemsBox   = Gtk2::Table->new(2, $ItemsCount+1, FALSE);

my  $View = Gtk2::Viewport->new();

$ScWin->set_policy('automatic', 'automatic');   
$View->add($ItemsBox);
$ScWin->add($View);

for my $i (0 .. $ItemsCount-1)  {
    my $exp =  Gtk2::Expander->new();
    $exp     ->set_label("Item #$i");
    $ItemsBox->attach($exp, 0, 1, $i, $i+1, 'fill', 'fill', 1, 2);
}
$MainBox    ->pack_start    ($ScWin     , TRUE, TRUE, 0);
```

Comment: Can you show a minimal (only using a single or a few expanders) working example of the gui (the scrolled window)? (as source code.) It would help to clarify your question. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: How is the code performance using [Gtk3](https://metacpan.org/pod/Gtk3) ? And how is the performance if you code it in C instead of Perl (is it independent of the language)?

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: Since it is `show_all()` that is taking time, I would guess that you would have the same problem if you programmed in C. The question then is why you need show 80000 widgets at the same time? Can you group them into sub groups for example using expanders?

Comment: After digging more i now use show not show_all, and i connect to scroll-event of the ScrolledWindow to detect when i need to show the item and when to hide it. To complete the picture i use the expander event expose-event to identify which items are shown after the scroll.

Comment: I was hopeing to find a simpler solution